# Need help to structure Eloquent Many to Many relationship (laravel 5.1)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am trying to build a 'facebook groups' style application, which contains groups filled with members, each member has a membership type (eg. admin, officer, user..) and each group has its group type (public, closed, secret).

so I created few tables:

```
users - (id, name ..)
groups - (id, name, group_type_id ..)  
group_types - (id, type)
group_members - (user_id, group_id, membership_type_id)
group_membership_types - (id, type)
```

I believe this is the proper approach to structure the DB (correct me if I wrong).

now I need to convert it to Eloquent models, so I created the models, but got really confused when trying to make the relationship between them, I read about 'pivot' and 'hasManyThrough' and got even more confuse.

theses are the models I created so far:

```
class Group extends BaseModel
{ 
    protected $table = 'groups';

    public function Members() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\GroupMemeber');
    }

    public function Type() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\GroupType');
    }
}
```

--

```
class GroupType extends BaseModel
{
   protected $table = 'group_types';

   protected $guarded = ['id', 'type'];

}
```

--

```
class GroupMemebershipType extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'group_membership_types';
}
```

--

```
class GroupMember extends BaseModel
{

    protected $table = 'group_members';

    public function User() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function Group() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Group');
    }

    public function MembershipType() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\GroupMemebershipType');
    }
}
```

---

am I doing it right? how would you create those models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pivot table conventions

Pivot tables are, by convention, named `tablename1_tablename2` where `tablename1` is alphabetically superseding `tablename2`. In this case, `group_members` should be `group_user`. If you change this, you don't need to define the $table variable, so you can remove those to clean up the code if you want.

## Eloquent relations

The Eloquent relationships are [well documented](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships), and if you are ever unsure you can always refer to the code documentation, which is pretty straight-forward:

**hasOne**

```
Define a one-to-one relationship.
```

**hasMany**

```
Define a one-to-many relationship.
```

**hasManyThrough**

```
Define a has-many-through relationship.
```

**belongsTo**

```
Define an inverse one-to-one or many relationship.
```

**belongsToMany**

```
Define a many-to-many relationship.
```

When using a pivot-table, you can add `->withPivot()` and Eloquent will automagically find your conventionally named pivot table. You don't even need models for these "middle"-objects, because they (probably) won't be used in your presentation-layer.

## Three-way pivot tables

Now, as for your group memberships, here is where things get a little complicated. The `hasManyThrough` relation is for [accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through), and is not what you are looking for. Laravel does not offer any "plug-and-play" functionality for this type of relationship, and while there [is a Laravel 4 library](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot) for this purpose, it is not very dynamic but only offers three-way functionality. This is fine for now, but what if you decide to expand on your pivot-table in the future? Then this would break.

## Restructuring the database

I looked over the structure of your tables, and noticed that it can easily be restructured:
[image: UML Diagram]

By avoiding the three-way pivot tables, your code (and table structure) is much more easily maintained and more readable. I think this applies to any pivot-table with three-way relations, and a good rule of thumb is to avoid it by using a smarter table structure.

## Result

### User

A user

- belongs to many memberships
- has many groups through memberships

Code:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function memberships() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Membership');
    }

    public function groups() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Group', 'App\Membership');
    }
}
```

### Membership

A membership

- has many users
- belongs to a group

Code:

```
class Membership extends Model
{
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }

    public function group() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Group');
    }
}
```

### Group

A group

- has many memberships
- has many users through memberships

Code:

```
class Group extends Model
{
    public function memberships() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Membership');
    }

    public function users() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Membership');
    }
}
```